# Choosing a Designpattern or Dependency injection

Tags: design-patterns

I have different components, which deliver data for export. After that data will be write to
`.xml`, `.csv`, `.xls` or `.docx` file.

For each type I have a writer component like

`XmlWriter`, `CsvWriter` etc.

At the moment I have an `if ... else` structure to decide which `Writer object` i want to use.

Is there exists a Design pattern which replace this `if ... else` structure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inversion of Control (IoC) in conjunction with Dependency Injection (DI) would be a good fit for this scenario. First, IoC allows to avoid concrete object coupling at compile-time while still knowing "some" implementation details, so, there's no direct dependencies between each other. Now, Dependency Injection as quoted by WikiPedia...

> Dependency injection is a software design pattern that allows the removal of hard-coded dependencies and makes it possible to change them, whether at run-time or compile-time

It allows you to switch between dependencies which is very powerful because you could actually change the implementation of an object without requiring to re-compile a whole project and re-deploy it by using other variants of the pattern such as the Factory Pattern or Service Locator Pattern because you can "inject" dependencies either at runtime or compile-time.

Now, how would you achieve that using your case scenario? At the least, you will need a concrete object that does all this job for you and hide implementation details....

```
public class DataExportManager
{
    private IDataExporter _exporter;

    public DataExportManager(IDataExporter exporter)
    {
       this._exporter = exporter;
    }

    public void ExportData()
    {
         this._exporter.Export();
    }
}
```

Notice that this class uses an interface `IDataExporter` to export the data but it doesn't know anything about the underlying concrete object that implements that interface it simply allows consumer code to "inject" the implementation details. needless to say that instead of taking an Interface in the constructor it could also take in a base class or an abstract class. Then you need to implement the concrete objects and the interface. The interface would look like this...

```
public interface IDataExporter 
{
    void Export();
}
```

and the implementations like this...

```
public WordDataExporter : IDataExporter
{
    public void Export(){//export to Word logic}
}


public PdfDataExporter : IDataExporter
{
    public void Export(){//export to pdf logic}
}


public ExcelDataExporter : IDataExporter
{
    public void Export(){//export to excel logic}
}
```

And so on. Then you know you've got an object `DataExportManager` that can be injected objects that implement the `IDataExporter` interface. That's Dependency Injection in action. But, how do you inject it? That's when IoC comes in handy. You could implement a factory object or a service locator to inject this DataExporters to your DataExportManager. A simplify version would be a simple object that determines which object to inject at compile time...

```
public class ExporterFactory
{
    public static IDataExporter GetCurrentExporter()
    {
        return new WordDataExporter();
    }
}
```

Then you would inject the `WordDataExporter` like this...

```
DataExportManager manager = new DataExportManager(ExportFactory.GetCurrentExporter());
```

The beauty of this is that you can change the object that implements the `IDataExporter` interface and without even noticing it `DataExportmanager` will start exporting to PDF, Excel or whatever you like. It's super simple and removes dependencies in your application layers. Of course, you can make it fancier and more intelligent than that.

You could even do this without having to re-compile your application if you make the `ExportFactory` read a config file to determine which `IDataExporter` it should serve.

There's pretty good and popular community project called [Windsor Castle](http://docs.castleproject.org/Default.aspx?Page=MainPage&NS=Windsor&AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1) that does this beautifully which goes even further to let you manage the lifetime of this dependencies and service locators.

Now, to answer your question. There's no design pattern that will replace the `if...else` or `switch...case`

Hope it helped

Comment: This help me a let to understand. but still have a question regarding ExporterFactory::GetCurrentExporter method. Here we will decide which writer to return using if...else or switch?

Comment: If you keep in mind that this is just an example...yes, that's where you'd add the logic to determine which concrete class you should return

Answer (score 1):

Not really a design pattern, but you could take each component and add an interface that has a method called `Write`, and then in each component class you can implement that interface and use the appropriate writer object.  That way instead of an `if ... else` you have a single command: `IComponentWriter.Write(params)`

If you want to use Dependency Injection (depending on the language you are writing in), you could add an `IWriter` property to each component class and then in your service locator you can map each class with a specific implementation of the `IWriter` interface, but this is almost the same as the giant `if .. else`, you've just moved the problem to the IoC class.

I would go with the Interface design at the beginning.

Comment: It is actually a design pattern